# Should I use `<ul>` or `<div>` on my navigation menu

Tags: html, css

Is it a bad practise or not professional when we write a navigation menu without the unordered list.

for example, using `<div>` tags instead.

```
<div class="navbar">
   <a href="#"> Home </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's mostly opinion based. It might be better practice for screen-readers and accessablilty to have it in an `<ul>` though.

Comment: I agree with @MartijnVissers. See this: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: It just makes it more organized you can see this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/. Which they used it depends on their need.

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 can you reference that `<ul>...<li>` is standardised for a menu system, rather than simply *common*?

Comment: Ahem `nav` is the **most** semantic method....whether it's a list or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML site development: div's vs ul's for navigation and menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828453/html-site-development-divs-vs-uls-for-navigation-and-menus)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a problem. Using a bunch of divs or using `<ul>` should be just an appearance matter. Even if using a `<ul>` can provide some context, it must be only used for styling proper unordered lists since we have more advanced tools to provide semantic for screen readers and search engines. And in the end, there is no a reason why not using a `<ul>` should be not professional.

So, what can we do to don't make screen readers fail in the attempt of finding where the main navigation buttons are?

Well, a good practice is to always use `role="navigation"` in the outer div containing the navigation buttons, [as stated here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Navigation_Role). You can use it in combination with the HTML5 tag `<nav>` to make it still clearer and perform a still better SEO.

This is the advised practice. But you don't have to use an unordered list just because you have to.

Comment: Nice to see someone referencing MDN rather than simply Bootstrap or W3Fools. `:-)`

Comment: @04FS care to share why not?

Comment: @04FS you are right, my answer wasn't clear enough so I edited it

Comment: @CristianTraìna cheers, I think that reads a bit better now. Using `ul` for navigations is a common practice these days, but you are right that the semantics of that are a bit questionable. It basically _is_ a “list of links”, but for users of assistive technology the actual benefit of using a `ul` might be rather small. Wrapping it in a `nav` or using ARIA attributes where appropriate, does more in that regard.

Answer (score -1):

I think yes, it is bad practice in a semantic way. But you can achieve the same functionality without an unordered list so dont care too much about this :)

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. I know your reputation is still too low, but this answer is more a *comment* than an actual answer. Can you **edit** and fill out your answer and add references, sources and establish your claims more fully? Cheers

Answer (score -2):

No it's not unprofessional to write navigation menu without **ul** . We can markup in many ways. You can also use HTML 5 tag available for navigation called **nav**.
But using **ul** makes the flow easier.